# Why does this C# code fail?

Tags: c#

This is matrix product which saves the answer in `C`, such that `C=A*B`. So why won't the `C` values change?

It uses special way that it calculates each column, because we want to use this method in Parallel programming such that each column evaluated in a single thread. I have tested something like this in pascal before, but in C# every thing is wrong.

Note: This is for homework and there is no parallel in this code yet.

```
class Program
{
    private static int n = 2;
    static int[,] A = new int[n, n];
    static int[,] B = new int[n, n];
    static int[,] C = new int[n, n];
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A[0, 0] = 2; A[0, 1] = 3;
        A[1, 0] = 5; A[1, 1] = 1;

        B[0, 0] = 3; B[0, 1] = 0;
        B[1, 0] = 1; B[1, 1] = 0;

        C[0, 0] = 0; C[0, 1] = 0;
        C[1, 0] = 0; C[1, 1] = 0;

        //Calculation 
        for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
        {
            ComputeColumn(z);
        }
        PrintAnswer(C);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void ComputeColumn(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                C[i, n] += (A[i, k] * B[k, n]);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void PrintAnswer(int[,] what)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(what[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could easily diagnose the problem using a debugger.

Comment: Here's a hint- which cell in C do you expect to see a change in?

Comment: here's another hint: what is the value of n in ComputeColumn() ?

Comment: The first thing that strikes me as *horribly wrong* is that you have a local and a static both named `n`. That sounds like a recipe for bugs to me. Whether that actually is your bug or not, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming the multiple uses of `n`

```
private static int n = 2;
ComputeColumn(int n)
```

to something more meaningful like

```
private static int NumberOfColumns = 2;
ComputeColumn(int currentColumn)
```

I think this will bring the problem to light fairly quickly.

Comment: Or something more meaningful like "NumberOfColumns". DO_NOT_WRITE_CONSTANTS_LIKE_IT_IS_STILL_1972.

Comment: @EricLippert lol agreed. I have no idea why I did that other than perhaps a subliminal infection from the A, B, and C.

Comment: The only time I would recommend using that style is for Win32 constants, but that's only for consistancy down to the metal. Otherwise, I completely agree.

Comment: @EricLippert What is wrong with upper case constants?

Comment: @GetAh: They violate style guidelines, for one thing. But more generally THEY LOOK LIKE THE CODE IS SHOUTING AT YOU. Also, constants are, in the grand scheme of things, not that important. Using all caps MEANS THAT THE relatively unimportant tokens IN THE document stand out, which steals focus from details that maybe the reader ought to be paying attention to.